# How to decode Kernel-Power Event 566 when waking from sleep

Tags: sleep, windows-11, event-viewer

On a Dell Vostro 3470 desktop running Windows-11 Pro 21H2 build 22000.795, while troubleshooting an issue related to waking up from sleep (yes S3 sleep, not Modern Standby, as this platform does not support S0) I encounter numerous events in `Event Viewer` > `Windows Logs` > `System` similar to this:
[image: Kernel-Power Event 566]
The events in question are all `Kernel-Power` events with `EventID` 566 and descriptive text such as `The system session has transitioned from xx to yy`.  The xx and yy differ, but yy is always one greater than xx.

As they are all `Information` events, I consider them non-critical.  But I simply cannot find any information anywhere that can tell me what they mean.  Although I have discovered [this](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winnt/ne-winnt-system_power_state) page, which enumerates and describes values from 0 through 7, the events I'm seeing routinely report values well above 7, as shown in the attached screen shot.  And I've found no information anywhere regarding how to decode the associated `Reason` (in the above case, Reason 32.)

Can anyone provide any assistance in decoding these events, the meanings of xx and yy, and how to interpret values for Reason?